# Can you "deliver at" or "deliver in" somewhere?

Tags: prepositions

I see a listing on the internet and want to ask seller, if he/she can deliver the product in some special place, which sentence is correct?

> 1. Can you deliver at LA?
> 2. Can you deliver in LA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you're ordering.  If you're ordering a product from a business outside of Los Angeles (assuming LA here is Los Angeles) and you want the business to mail the product to LA, you'd ask:

> Can you deliver to LA?

If you're asking a company that provides delivery as part of its regular business operations (like a restaurant that delivers food), or if you're asking a standalone delivery service itself (like UPS), you'd then ask the question:

> Do you deliver in LA?

Answer (score 0):

"At" is not usually used for locales like cities, states, or countries. "In LA" is correct (assuming it means Los Angeles).